# Unable to load default aspx web page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, iis-7

I have published my website in a directory called `samp` and i am currently trying to host it on IIS.

However i have numerous `aspx` pages. For example, `members.aspx`, `default.aspx`, `authenticate.aspx`, etc.

But i am not sure how do i make `default.aspx` to load when the user connects to `localhost` at port 80.

I am new at this, please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable it through the `Web.config` file in your ASP.net website.

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument enabled="true">
     <files>
        <add value="Default.aspx" />
     </files>
  </defaultDocument>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Note:** This is especially important if you're debugging with **IISExpress** (i.e. inside Visual Studio 2015), where you don't heve the option to configure your default files directly (as in IIS - see [freefaller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10211972/1016343)).

Answer (score 0):

In IIS7 click on the website in question (under the "Sites" area of the left-hand tree), then find "Default Document" in the IIS group of icons.  Double click the icon to go into the section, then click "Add..." in the Actions panel and then add "default.aspx" in the dialog.

You can then set the order of precedence by clicking on the new entry and moving it to the top of the list using the "Move Up" option in the Actions panel.

This will allocate the default document to the website in question - if you want it adding to ALL websites on IIS7, then do the same thing to the top level icon (the one under "Start Page")